# Select a default radio button from another page

Tags: radio-button, hyperlink

I am trying to place a series of links on one page that, when clicked, will select a default value of a radio group on another page. The perfect example of this is [here](http://www.studentsfirst.org/pages/membership). By clicking one of the blue links on the far right, they define the default value of the radio group on the next page. That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Can anyone help me understand how they did that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't 'checking' the box on the other end.  The link that you're clicking contains a variable in the URL (GET variable).  When the new page loads, it's likely using a server-side scripting language to test for each radio button.

In this case, ?default_amt=5 is what is attached for the $5 contribution.  Then, on the page:

```
 <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="5" name="amount" id="amt_preset_1" onclick="BSD.contribution.clearother();" class="radiobutton">
```

Is the value for the radio button.  Simply put something like this php code to 'check' it

```
 <?php if ($_GET['default_amt'] == "5") {echo "checked=\"checked\"; } ?>
```

The links on the previous page could be this:

```
 <a href="newpage.html?amount=1">Set amount to 1 on new page</a>
 <a href="newpage.html?amount=2">Set amount to 2 on new page</a>
 <a href="newpage.html?amount=3">Set amount to 3 on new page</a>
 <a href="newpage.html?amount=4">Set amount to 4 on new page</a>
```

'newpage.html' would have the following:

```
 <input type="radio" value="1" name="toPay"  <?php if ($_GET['amount'] == "1") {echo "checked=\"checked\"; } ?>>
 <input type="radio" value="2" name="toPay"  <?php if ($_GET['amount'] == "2") {echo "checked=\"checked\"; } ?>>
 <input type="radio" value="3" name="toPay"  <?php if ($_GET['amount'] == "3") {echo "checked=\"checked\"; } ?>>
 <input type="radio" value="4" name="toPay"  <?php if ($_GET['amount'] == "4") {echo "checked=\"checked\"; } ?>>
```

Comment: OK, so I place that code on the destination page. What I am unsure about (I've been having a hard time with php) is how does that code specify a radio option?

Comment: The first code example I gave that begins with <input> is for that particular radio button.  Radio buttons get grouped when you make multiple instances of that <input> field and they share the same 'name'.  The radio button that is selected will have the extra definition of 'checked=checked' inside the <input> tag.  The php is testing the GET variable in the URL, and in this case if it is '5', sets that radio button as 'checked'.  The php code I gave in the second example needs to be included for each <input>, with a unique variable for each.

Comment: You should really read up on HTML forms and inputs.  w3schools.com is an excellent resource for a basic overview - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: I'm all set with understanding forms and inputs and radios, I'm just having a hard time understanding php well. I am confused on how the snippet of php code you gave me relates to the inputs. How does that code know which radio it is interacting with?

Comment: I updated my answer with more a more detailed example.  You're just using PHP to test the GET variable in the URL and then in the proper place write 'checked=checked'.

Comment: Worked beautifully. I didn't think you could nest one tag within another like that. I've never seen that before, but if a site is using server side code, I wouldn't. Thanks.